# Component / Circuit for variable resistance (0, 5K, 100K) at 110V and 1.5Amps @ 0Ohm

Tags: circuit-design, component-selection, digital-potentiometer

I am searching for a circuit or component, lets call it IC1, which can deliver varieieng resistance with zero capacitance for a power output.
When IC1 has 0 Ohms, there will be 110V and 1.5AmpsMax pulses (capacitive load).
5K and 100K should be possible.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flcoDA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Currently I am thinking of a relais and digital potentiometer. But are there potis which have 0Ohms and can hold 1.5Amps@110V? 
The Tolerance can be 20%. But up till now, I found no poti which has the 0Ohm, or when f.e. LSB = 0.6 and wiper is 400 Ohm, I can assume that I have 0.6*400 Ohms at input == 0V?

Are there simpler solutions, or other ICs which can do that?

To add, the circuit will be controlled by an IC, so a normal poti is no option.

Comment: There are no digital potentiometers that will meet that spec, you might want to look into motorized potentiometers though...

Comment: Try explaining what you require without mentioning the tech that might be involved.

Comment: I want to be able to insert a resistor (0Ohms, 5K and 100K) between the source and load. This pretty much sums it up.
Currenlty the most reasonable approach looks like a relay which either shorts a digital poti or puts the poti into the line.

Comment: @Eggi no, please explain to what *end*, for what *purpose* you want to add that resistor.

Comment: The load is a device which behaves like a cap. The 0 Ohm is for normal operation. The 5k is to measure the capacitance and the 100k are for protection from false cabeling (switch 110V and GND). I can't measure the capacitance with 100k for some reasons, 5K is the minimum and maximum because of the limitations of some already existing adcs and voltage dividers. 5K is not good for protection because it would need a 3Watt upwards resistor.

Comment: @Eggi better! If you told us what the device *actually* is, instead of what you declare it to be *like*, answers might have been even more helpful! "Can't measure for some reason" really screams "are we really solving the problem, or just [something you *think* will help you](http://xyproblem.info)"; we call that the *XY Problem*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of SPST relays will do what you want:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flNdoG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By default (no relays activated), the 100k protection resistor is in the circuit.

Activate RLY1 to make a measurement.

Activate RLY2 to operate.